# make a function callback outside of $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
    ..
    ..
    success:function(response){

    }
    });
    }

$('button').click(function(){
ajax() <-- if success do after this

});

$('.button2').click(function(){
ajax() <-- if success do after this

});
```

I have few element that need to run a ajax function but how can I do a callback? since ajax is async I can't simply run something after the function.

Comment: Umm, I am a little confused. So i can see that when you click the button, you make an ajax call. Do you want to run something once the ajax call is done?

Comment: You can pass anything ( e.g. functions ) to ajax and then just simple call it in success callback.

Comment: @Pratik yes. but I want to make my $.ajax as a function.

Comment: @kuba my success callback will have 5 condition if i have 5 button? that's redundant.

Comment: Is that what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/g3zcd2yx/

Comment: This is how you can pull your code out into a separate callback function and pass the parameters around: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/k57bnn0a/1/